# Creating array from dynamic formatted date keys

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a hash that uses the year-month as a key.  Consider this code:

```
(start_date..end_date).map { |date| date.strftime('%Y-%m') }.uniq
```

The above code creates an array of dates formatted, that looks like below:

```
["2017-05", "2017-06", "2017-07", "2017-08", "2017-09", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", "2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05"]
```

However, how would you do something similar that would use this formatted date as key with an empty array as value?  That looks something like this:

```
{ "2017-05": [], "2017-06": [], "2017-07": [] ...}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually take your approach and build upon it:

```
(start_date..end_date)
  .map { |date| date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
  .uniq
  .map { |date| [date, []] }
  .to_h

=> {"2017-05"=>[], "2017-06"=>[], "2017-07"=>[], "2017-08"=>[], "2017-09"=>[], "2017-10"=>[], "2017-11"=>[], "2017-12"=>[], "2018-01"=>[], "2018-02"=>[], "2018-03"=>[], "2018-04"=>[], "2018-05"=>[]}
```

But this can be simplified to:

```
(start_date..end_date)
  .map { |date| [date.strftime('%Y-%m') , []] }
  .to_h
```

The dates created by the range will already be unique.

Comment: I was just about to come in an answer my own question, as I figured it out. But you beat me to it! But good to know for people in the future!  THANKS!

Comment: And even shorter: ```(start_date..end_date).inject({}) { |memo, date| memo[date.strftime('%Y-%m')] = []; memo }```